# java making noises from main and class of a transport

Tags: java

How do I make the method "sound" change when car.sound(); is called to do vroom or train.sound(); when called to do choo choo? My if statement doesn't make sense and is not even valid, so I am confused how I can achieve this?

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main (String[] args)                                       
  {                                     
    Transport car = new Transport();                                        
    car.make = "Audi";                                      
    Transport train = new Transport();                                      
    train.make = "Thomas";                                      

    System.out.println(car.make);                                       
    car.sound();
    train.sound();                                  
  }                                     
}
```

---

```
public class Transport                                      
{                                       
  public String make;                                       
  public void sound()                                       
  {                                     
    if (this.sound == car){                                                         
      car.sound = "vroom";                                      
    } 
     else if (this.sound == train){
      train.sound = "choo choo";                        
  }                                     
}
```

Comment: Take a look at how to use `Interface`. You need to have some other property defining what the object is apart from the variable name. You can add another property or use interfaces.

Comment: Please read here: https://www.javatpoint.com/interface-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Like people have mentioned use Interfaces. An interface allows you to have many different types of for example `Transport` such as a car or a train but they may share common functionality such as make a sound.

First create your interface that contains the common functionality:
Example:

```
public interface ITransport
{
   void sound();
}
```

Next create your concrete implementations that could be a type of Transport:

```
public class Car implements ITransport
{                                       
  public String make; 

  @override                                
  public void sound()                                       
  {                                                                                      
      System.out.println("Vroom!");                                                        
  }                                     
}


public class Train implements ITransport
{                                       
  public String make; 

  @override                       
  public void sound()                                       
  {                                                                                      
      System.out.println("Choo Choo!");                                                        
  }                                     
}
```

Then when you run your code in the main:

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main (String[] args)                                       
  {                                     
    ITransport car = new Car();                                        
    car.make = "Audi";                                      
    ITransport train = new Train();                                      
    train.make = "Thomas";                                      

    System.out.println(car.make);                                       
    car.sound();
    train.sound();                                  
  }                                     
}
```

But I would suggest also looking at encapsulation because as of right now everything is public and you don't want that really. For example in the main method the way you access `car.make = "Audi"` is not really the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it besides using an interface if you're interested. You can use an abstract class. A cool thing about abstract classes versus interfaces is that you can define non-static methods and fields within it. Everything that extends the abstract class will also have those fields and methods. Interfaces only allow static and default methods to have definitions in them, and that's only true if using Java 8+.

Here's an example of using an abstract method:

```
abstract class Transport{
    abstract void sound();
}

class Car extends Transport{

    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("vroom vroom");
    }

}

class Train extends Transport{

    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("choo choo");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car car = new Car();
    Train train = new Train();

    car.sound();
    train.sound();
}
```